# Make the home directory of a newly created user invisible to other users

Tags: linux, terminal

I need to make the home directory of a new user, invisible to the other users. I know I have to use `usermod` but I don't really know the proper attributes or the correct syntax of it.

Comment: What to you mean by invisible?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [man usermod](https://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod) you set the home directory with the `--home` switch. The following line will create user `GDB` with comment `Stack overflow user` with home directory in `/home/GDB`:

```
usermod --comment "Stack overflow user" --home /home/GDB GDB
```

If you want `/home/GDB` to be unaccessible by other users, only by GDB, just remove group and other permissions from it and make sure this directory is owned by GDB:

```
chown GDB /home/GDB
chmod u+rwx /home/GDB
chmod go-rwx /home/GDB
```

That way other users can't get into /home/GDB. But i don't thing there is a way to make this folder disappear for other users.
Every user you create has an entry in `/etc/passwd`, in the format (see [man 5 passwd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html)):

```
name:password:UID:GID:GECOS:directory:shell
```

This file is visible by all, so any user may see what other users exists and where their home directories is, what is their encrypted passwd.

Comment: Being not accessible by other users is the default setting for a home directory if it has been created by useradd

Comment: This depends on the UMASK setting.